# Show that exist $p\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $p^3+p=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that there exists $p\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $p^3+p=1$.

How can I prove it? I was thinking in what can I do to prove it but I really stuck .

I just see supreme axiom, Archimedean property and sequences.

Any hint of what I can do?

Comment: $p=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(9+\sqrt{93}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3
   \left(9+\sqrt{93}\right)}}$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(p) = p^{3} + p - 1$. Then $f$ is continuous because it is a polynomial.

Moreover, we also have that $f(0) = -1$ and $f(1) = 1$.

Given that $f(0) < 0 < f(1)$, we conclude (through the IVT) there exists $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: +1. A remark that one can use this approach with the IVT to show that *any* cubic polynomial has a root in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Dave why stop at cubics? This works for any odd degree polynomial :)

Answer (score 1):

From algebra we know that real coefficient polynomial equations if a complex $\alpha$ is a root, then  its conjugate $\overline{\alpha}$ is a root, too. Therefore odd degree polynomial equations have at least one real root.

Answer (score 0):

In case your course hasn't covered IVT yet:

Consider the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x^3+x-1<0\}$, which is non-empty (e.g. $0\in S$). As $f(x)=x^3+x-1$ is increasing, $S$ is bounded above (e.g. by $1$). So let $s=\sup S$ (which exists by Archimedean property). We claim that $f(s)=0$.

Let $\varepsilon=|f(s)|$, and suppose $\varepsilon>0$. As $f$ is continuous, we can take $\delta$ such that $\lvert f(s)-f(t)\rvert<\varepsilon$ whenever $\lvert s-t\rvert<\delta$.

If $f(s)<0$, then $f(s+\delta/2)<0$ too, contradicting that $s$ is an upper bound. If $f(s)>0$, then $f(t)>0$ whenever $s-\delta<t<s+\delta$, so $s-\delta/2$ would be a smaller upper bound, again a contradiction.

---

With very little effort, this proof can be generalised to prove the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function $$p^3+p-1.$$ Its derivative wrt $p$ is $$3p^2+1,$$ which is always positive. Hence the function is always increasing. Since for $p\to-\infty$ the function is negative, it follows that it vanishes at some value of $p.$